# Syncing a paper-input with firebase using polymer

Tags: firebase, polymer, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-polymer

How is this for a solution for syning the data from a paper input to a firebase database.

```
properties: {
            teamid: {
                type: String,
                value: null
            },
            formid: {
                type: String,
                value: null
            },

            metaName: {
                type: String, 
                value: null,
                observer: '_updateMetaName'
            }
        },


        _updateMetaName: function(metaName) {
            var path = 'formModel/' + this.teamid + '/' + this.formid + '/meta/name';

            firebase.database().ref(path).set(metaName);
        },
```

The data *metaName* comes from a a paper-input element

```
<paper-input value="{{metaName}}"></paper-input>
```

I'm using an observer over the on-change attribute because I hate the idea that a user must move out of an input for it to persist. 
I've also chosen not to use PolymerFire because i dosen't have some features I need and its not production ready.

I also don't like the idea that the observer runs multiple times before any data has been changed. And that should, i thought, break it but its working to my surprise.

What other options do I have?
Are their any disadvantages to my current solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One disadvantage is that every keystroke fires off a request to Firebase, which could be inefficient (a waste of CPU and bandwidth).

To address this, you could debounce the callback with [`this.debounce(jobName, callback, wait)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-debounce), as shown in the following demo.

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(_ => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties : {
      metaName: {
        type: String,
        value: 'Hello world!',
        observer: '_metaNameChanged'
      }
    },
    _setFirebaseMetaName: function(metaName) {
      var path = 'formModel/' + this.teamid + '/' + this.formid + '/meta/name';
      //firebase.database().ref(path).set(metaName);
      console.log('metaName', metaName);
    },
    _metaNameChanged: function(metaName) {
      this.debounce('keyDebouncer',
                    _ => this._setFirebaseMetaName(metaName),
                    500);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.5.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-input label="Meta Name" value="{{metaName}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/Nrdodb?editors=1011)

Comment: What does this ```_ =>``` do?

Comment: That's an [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). It's shorthand for a parameterless callback (technically the underscore is a parameter that we ignore): `function(_) {}`, which is equivalent to `function() {}`.

Answer (score 1):

I've decided to go with `on-keyup="_updateViewDesc"` to stop a error occurring when multiple clients have the same page open. Using observers, when some data updates, it triggers the observer on all the connected clients. Causing characters to go missing.